# Clear unwanted <span> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clear some unwanted  tags. This is the HTML I have:

```
<span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <a href="http://dummy.com/image.jpg">[Image]</a>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

And this is the result I'm looking for:

```
<span>
    <a href="http://dummy.com/image.jpg">[Image]</a>
</span>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this easily? Thanks for any help.

The HTML is rendered by a code base that I can't change so I have to try to fix it using JS.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have more context? Where do these spans come from? Are they rendered inside your DOM or just in a .html file that you can edit? The best solution in these cases is always to just fix whatever generates the unwanted HTMLto begin with instead of fixing it elsewhere.

Comment: @CoderPi nothing even close to working. I was dabbling around with removing span-children.

Comment: @Shilly I'm sorry for not being clear in the question. I'll update it. This HTML is rendered by a code base that I really can't change, I have to try to fix it using some JS.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). The following example would remove all span nesting in the entire document so you may have to be more restrictive in your case.

However, even though you can fix the problematic DOM structure after it's been constructed it's probably a better idea to fix the problem at the source.

```js
$('span').unwrap('span');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <a href="http://dummy.com/image.jpg">[Image]</a>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked like a charm. I can't really fix it in the source (see the updated question).